# form not submitting when I am calling the ID in jquery but when I change the id to class the form submits

Tags: jquery, html

this is my jquery, I don't see any errors on my jquery but still when I call the form in my jquery the function is not loading and the button won't fire

this is my form, As you can see the ID of my form is lessonForm but I can't call the form from my function, I don't know if I'm blind or not but I'm spending hours just to fix this, but still the same result

When I call the Id from my form the button is not working, I can't find the fix what seems to be the problem

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ajaxloader").hide();
  $('#file').change(function(e){
    var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
    $("#url").val(fileName);
    var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
  });
 });
   function addLess() 
   {
    $('#lessonForm').unbind('submit').bind('submit',function(){
       var lessonname = $("#lessonname").val();
       var lessondesc = $("#lessondesc").val();
       var url = $("#url").val();
       var lessoncode = $("#lessoncode option:selected").val();
 

       if (url == "")
       {
         $("#pw-msg").html("LESSON REQUIRED.");
         $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
         $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
       }

       if(lessonname == "")
       {
        $("#pw-msg").html("LESSON NAME REQUIRED.");
        $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
        $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
       }

       if(lessondesc == "")
       {
        $("#pw-msg").html("LESSON NAME REQUIRED.");
        $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
        $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
       }
       if(lessoncode == "")
       {
        $("#pw-msg").html("LESSON CODE REQUIRED.");
        $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
        $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
       }


       if(url && lessonname && lessondesc && lessoncode) 
       { 
        var form = $(this);
         var formData = new FormData(this);
         $(".formcontent").hide();
         $(".ajaxloader").show();
         $.ajax({
           url : form.attr('action'),
           type: form.attr('method'),
           data: form.serialize(),
           data: formData,
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           success:function(response)
           {
             if(response.success == true)
             {
               $(".ajaxloader").hide();
               $("#lessonForm")[0].reset();
               $("#addlesson").modal('hide');
               $(".formcontent").show();
               $("#ps-msg").html(response.messages);
               $(".lead").html("SUCCESS");
               $('#prompt-success').modal('show');
             } 
             // if
             else if(response.success == false) 
             {
               $(".ajaxloader").hide();
               $(".formcontent").show();
               $("#pw-msg").html(response.messages);
               $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
               $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
             }  // if
           },
           error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             $(".ajaxloader").hide();
             $(".formcontent").show();
             $("#pw-msg").html("CONNECTION ERROR, TRY AGAIN.");
             $(".lead").html("OOPS!");
             $('#prompt-warning').modal('show');
           } 
         }); // /ajax 
      } // if
         return false;
     }); //end bind unbind
 } //end func
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="addlesson" tabindex="-1" role='dialog' aria-labelledby="addlesson1"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="addlesson1">Add Lesson</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form class="form-horizontal" id="lessonForm" action="B/addLesson.php" method="POST" name="lessonForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="col-12 ajaxloader">
                  <div class="md-form mb-4">
                    <p class="card-text text-center mb-3">Adding Lesson...</p>
                    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-4x"></i>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                   <div class="file-field formcontent md-form">
                    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-left">
                      <span>Choose file</span>
                      <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper form-content">
                      <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload your file" id="url" name="url">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 formcontent">
                  <input type="text" name="lessoname" id="lessonname" class="form-control validate" placeholder="Lesson Name" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="off">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 formcontent mt-3 md-form">
                  <textarea  name="lessondesc" id="lessondesc" class="md-textarea w-100" rows="5"></textarea>
                  <label for="lessondesc">Lesson Description</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12 formcontent mb-3">
                  <select class="browser-default custom-select" name="lessoncode">
                  <option disabled="" selected="">Class List</option>
                   <?php  echo $classlist; ?>
                  </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block" onclick="addLess();">Add Lesson</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Did you try avoiding the chaining of `off` and `on`?

Comment: Yes and btw @AdarshMohan this is the only problem that I encounter in my function, I have 3 submit buttons that are working but this one isnt

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one element with the id `lessonForm`? if there are multiple elements with same id (id should be unique), the jquery selector will select only the first one.

Comment: @AdarshMohan Yes thats the only form with lessonForm ID

Comment: Can you cross check again,? I couldn't find anything wrong. Please use the view source on the page and search for the word `lessonForm`?

Comment: I cross check it, in the page source there is 4 2 for the form and 2 for the jquery
@AdarshMohan

Comment: That's the problem. Make them unique and it will work.

Comment: @AdarshMohan I am calling the lessonForm in my jquery, but the # selector is not working

Comment: The #selector will select only the first matching id.. if there are forms sharing the same id, only the first one will be selected by jQuery. You can find the reference [here](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: Yes I know that, im just calling the #lessonForm from my jquery, I have only 1 form containg #LessonForm

Comment: Not just on the form. but on how many elements do you have the id `lessonForm`?

Comment: @Adarsh Mohan, Just one element

Comment: @AdarshMohan I updated the form and query, so you can see it more clearly

Comment: I have updated your code to snippet. When you run the code you can see an error appearing on the ajax's error callback regarding a `modal` not found.. So that means the code is working fine and the event is getting attached. I couldn't see any issue with the code.

Comment: how can i see the error in the snippet? @AdarshMohan

Comment: It will show an error (console error) on the bottom of the output section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the problem is.. You can see two forms with the same id `sample-2` and the event will get attached to the first one only. If you click on the buttons, you can see that the output generates for the first one, but the second one will be submitted as the events are not attached to the second one.

```js
var formSubmit = function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('#output').html('form submitted with id ' + this.id + ' with data ' + $(this).serialize());
  return false;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#sample-1').off('submit').on('submit', formSubmit);
  $('#sample-2').off('submit').on('submit', formSubmit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="sample-1">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="sample-1" />
  <input type="submit" name="sample-1" value="Submit form with id sample-1" />
</form>

<form id="sample-2">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="sample-2 first form" />
  <input type="submit" name="sample-2-1" value="Submit first form with id sample-2" />
</form>

<form id="sample-2">
  <input type="hidden" name="form" value="sample-2 second form" />
  <input type="submit" name="sample-2-2" value="Submit second form with id sample-2" />
</form>

<hr />

<div id="output">You will see the output here.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit(()=>{
    console.log('do something here');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="target" action="">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <button id="other"></button>
</form>
```

**Try this**